# android-load map before fragment gets visible

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have 2 fragments in my app, one of them includes a `MapView`. when the user clicks on a button, the second fragment which includes the MapView gets visible (it's already been created). the problem is that the map is not already loaded and starts to load only after its containing fragment gets visible. how to load it beforehand?

```
    final Explore explore= Explore.newInstance();
    final Map map= Map.newInstance();

    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.holder, map).hide(map).commit();
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.holder, explore).commit();

    bottomNavigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_collection_explore: {
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(map).show(explore).commit();
                    break;
                }
                case R.id.nav_collection_map: {
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(explore).show(map).commit();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post your full code so that we can reproduce this issue from our side?

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Zookey no! I didn't work on that project any more. but I think you have to look for some methods to initialize the map view.